# youtube Add Subscription via C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am building a YouTube app for windows 8.1.

I am having a trouble with, add(Insert) subscription is fail

**my code:**

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
                new[] { Uri.EscapeUriString(YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube) },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None);

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "AppName"
                });

Subscription body = new Subscription();
body.Snippet = new SubscriptionSnippet();

body.Snippet.ChannelId = "UC-kezFAw46x-9ctBUqVe86Q"; 
try
{
    var addSubscriptionRequest = youtubeService.Subscriptions.Insert(body, "snippet");
    var addSubscriptionResponse = await addSubscriptionRequest.ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at the first line.

when execute to last line, breaks this function

Update(2015-11-14):

**Error Message:**
*The subscription resource specified in the request must use the  `snippet.resorceId`  property to identify the channel that is being subscribed to [400]*

**Successful Code:**

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
         new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
         new[] { Uri.EscapeUriString(YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube) },
         "user",
         CancellationToken.None);

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    //ApiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "4GameTV"
});


try
{
    Subscription body = new Subscription();
    body.Snippet = new SubscriptionSnippet();
    body.Snippet.ResourceId = new ResourceId();
    body.Snippet.ResourceId.ChannelId = "UC-kezFAw46x-9ctBUqVe86Q";  //replace with specified channel id

    var addSubscriptionRequest = youtubeService.Subscriptions.Insert(body, "snippet");
    var addSubscriptionResponse = await addSubscriptionRequest.ExecuteAsync();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authentication seems a bit off from what I normally use. Also ApiKey  is only needed if you want to access public data.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };


 // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
, scopes
, "test"
, CancellationToken.None
, new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
     {
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "YouTube Data API Sample",
     });
```

Comment: what is FileDataStore? is this a class?

Comment: File data store that implements IDataStore. This store creates a different file for each combination of type and key. This file data store stores a JSON format of the specified object.   It saves your authentication so you wont be requested to authenticate again.   Its where the refresh token will live.

Comment: that sounds so difficult =(, could you provide some webpage so that I can understand what you say, thanks.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about it a while ago http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/ Examples are for Google drive but you should get the idea.

Comment: thx for your reply. I had checked that website. It seems like to teach how to restore, refresh token. My token exist permanently, so I don't think that is the problem. I say this because my original code work on [Delete Subscription] function. or other codes have problem?

Comment: you said it breaks when you set a break point at the first line the first line is your authentication.  There for there must be a problem with your authentication.

Comment: sorry, my English is so poor...I mean it breaks when execute to last line code

Comment: var addSubscriptionResponse = addSubscriptionRequest.Execute();

Comment: sorry, replace with Execute() still crash. and it doesn't show any error message, just break function. I really have no idea how to fix it  =(

Comment: Did you try adding a try catch c# dosent just break without giving a reason

Comment: thanks you agin, DalmTo. I add try catch, and got the error message, I had updated the above content. Plz take a look.